# Eclipse svn code changes notification plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins, commit, trunk

I was wondering - is there a plugin for eclipse that will notify all the contributors to a certain svn project that someone has commited in trunk with some message containing the names of the changed classes and can afterwards show a diff between the changed/unchanged versions of the classes commited.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has these projects checked out and are using a plugin like Subclipse, they can just use the Team > Synchronize option.  This can be configured to refresh automatically every hour or whatever interval is desired.  The Synchronize view lets you examine the changes.

Comment: Synchronizing will synchronize only with the branch I currently work in. I'm more looking for something that will show a notification that someone has committed in trunk and when I click on this notification I want to see a diff between the previous and the current version of these files in trunk.

Comment: I have installed eclipse 4.3 with subclipse, but i do not see this option. Is it still avaialble?

Comment: Yes.  If you do not see Team > Synchronize on your project, then it must not be connected to a source control provider.